# ElasticSearch Doesn't Return Data Through Nest Call with Dynamic class

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Am new to Elastic search and NEST, I am trying to get connected with my ES server through NEST. My ES Connection initialization looks like below.

```
ElasticClient client = null;
        public  void Connect()

        {

            var local = new Uri("http://192.168.40.95:9200/");

            var settings = new ConnectionSettings(local).DisableDirectStreaming();

            client = new ElasticClient(settings);

            settings.DefaultIndex("gisgcc18q4");

            ReadAllData();
        }

        public void ReadAllData()
        {
           var x= client.Search<dynamic>(s=> s.MatchAll());
        }
```

The response is attached as image below,
[image]

I am Never getting any Hits, or data. Did i made any mistake in my connector, Also please suggest me good tutorials to convert JSOn ES query to NEST as well.

Comment: This problem usually does not come and your code looks fine. Are you sure that your index "gisgcc18q4" has some data? Try following Get request in POSTMAN etc   => http://192.168.40.95:9200/gisgcc18q4/_count

Comment: {"count":153453,"_shards":{"total":1,"successful":1,"skipped":0,"failed":0}} This is the response

Comment: What are your Elastic search  and Nest package versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the Uri in the screenshot

```
POST /gisgcc18q4/object/_search?typed_keys=true
```

suggests that you're using a version older than 7, such as 5 or 6, where document types are used. In this case, the document type name `"object"` has been inferred from the `dynamic` type passed as the generic parameter argument, but I suspect that documents have not been indexed with a document type name of `"object"`, but something else.

If the index "gisgcc18q4" only contains one type of document, you can use

```
var x = client.Search<dynamic>(s=> s.MatchAll().AllTypes());
```

Or you can pass the specific document type name to use

```
var x = client.Search<dynamic>(s=> s.MatchAll().Type("_doc"));
```

A good getting started tutorial for the client is the [elasticsearch-net-example](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net-example) GitHub repository. It is a walkthrough in building out a ASP.NET Core web application to search Nuget packages.

Answer (score 1):

Your connection looks fine, can you please validate the detailed summary under DebugInfrormation by clicking on it and get the row query and response.

After apply same query on Postman.

Please copy and paste below expression on quick watch window on the same line which is displayed in your screenshot.

```
((Elasticsearch.Net.ApiCallDetails)response.ApiCall).DebugInformation
```

You will get the detailed information, it will be helpful for you to investigate this issue.